# Reshape / Transform an upper triangular matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, transformation

I have an upper triangular matrix (without the diagonal) given by:

```
M = [0 3 2 2 0 0; 0 0 8 6 3 2; 0 0 0 3 2 1; 0 0 0 0 2 1; 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

The resulting matrix should look like this:

```
R = [0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 2 0 0 0 0; 2 3 1 0 0 0; 2 6 2 1 0 0; 3 8 3 2 0 0]
```

Since I couldn't find a simple explanation which describes my goal I tried to visualize it with an image:

[image]

I already tried lots of different combinations of `rot90`, `transpose`, `flipud` etc., but I could't find the right transformation that gives me the matrix `R`

EDIT:

The rows of the matrix `M` are not always sorted as in the example above. For another matrix `M_2`:

```
M_2 = [0 2 3 1 0 0; 0 0 3 6 3 9; 0 0 0 1 2 4; 0 0 0 0 2 6; 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

the resulting matrix `R_2` need to be the following:

```
R_2 = [0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 9 0 0 0 0; 1 3 4 0 0 0; 3 6 2 6 0 0; 2 3 1 2 0 0]
```

Again the visualization below:

[image]

Comment: What about `sort(M')`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to have that row of zeroes on the right, rather than on the top? Otherwise the solution by @Dan should do it.

Comment: hm...yes, the dimensions need to be the same, but `sort` seems like a good start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Inspired by the tip from @Dan's comment, it can be further simplified to

```
R = reshape(rot90(M), size(M));
```

**Original Answer:**

This should be a simple way to do this

```
F = rot90(M);
R = F(reshape(1:numel(M), size(M)))
```

which returns

```
R =
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     2     0     0     0     0
     2     3     1     0     0     0
     2     6     2     1     0     0
     3     8     3     2     0     0
```

The idea is that when you rotate the matrix you get

```
>> F = rot90(M)
F =
     0     2     1     1     0
     0     3     2     2     0
     2     6     3     0     0
     2     8     0     0     0
     3     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

which is a 6 by 5 matrix. If you consider the linear indexing over F the corresponding indices are

```
>> reshape(1:30, size(F))
     1     7    13    19    25
     2     8    14    20    26
     3     9    15    21    27
     4    10    16    22    28
     5    11    17    23    29
     6    12    18    24    30
```

where elements 6, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18 , and ... are zero now if you reshape this to a 5 by 6 matrix you get

```
>> reshape(1:30, size(M))
     1     6    11    16    21    26
     2     7    12    17    22    27
     3     8    13    18    23    28
     4     9    14    19    24    29
     5    10    15    20    25    30
```

Now those elements corresponding to zero values are on top, exactly what we wanted. So by passing this indexing array to `F` we get the desired `R`.

Comment: Nice, that's easy to understand.

Comment: Why not just `R = reshape(F, size(M))`?

Comment: @Dan That's actually true. I was so into explaining it I totally forgot it could be further simplified. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Without relying on order (just rotating the colored strips and pushing them to the bottom).

First solution: note that it doesn't work if there are zeros between the "data" values (for example, if `M(1,3)` is `0` in the example given). If there may be zeros please see second solution below:

```
[nRows nCols]= size(M);
R = [flipud(M(:,2:nCols).') zeros(nRows,1)];
[~, rowSubIndex] = sort(~~R);
index = sub2ind([nRows nCols],rowSubIndex,repmat(1:nCols,nRows,1));
R = R(index);
```

Second solution: works even if there are zeros within the data:

```
[nRows nCols]= size(M);
S = [flipud(M(:,2:nCols).') zeros(nRows,1)];
mask = 1 + fliplr(tril(NaN*ones(nRows, nCols)));
S = S .* mask;
[~, rowSubIndex] = sort(~isnan(S));
index = sub2ind([nRows nCols],rowSubIndex,repmat(1:nCols,nRows,1));
R = S(index);
R(isnan(R)) = 0;
```

Comment: @Shai Just a quick way of writing R~=0

Comment: @NLuisMendo Technically not quicker, because it evaluates two boolean operations instead of one...

Comment: @EitanT I meant quick to type, not to execute :-) Using `logical(R)` is probably the quickest in terms of computation time

Comment: @LuisMendo Actually I've had lousy experience regarding the performance of `logical`, so I doubt it's faster, but you're welcome to check this assertion for yourself :)

Comment: @ElianT Using

`function nada
R = [0     0     0     0     0     0;
     0     9     0     0     0     0;
     1     3     4     0     0     0;
     0     6     2     6     0     0;
     2     3     1     2     0     0];
tic, for n=1:1e6, logical(R); end, toc
tic, for n=1:1e6, R~=0; end, toc`

I get

`Elapsed time is 0.370217 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.378757 seconds.`

So `logical` seems to very slightly quicker (R2010b, Win7)

Comment: @ElianT Actually there was a new line there, but it won't show properly in comments

Answer (score 1):

Alternate option, using loops:

```
[nRows nCols]= size(M);
R = zeros(nRows,nCols);
for n = 1:nRows
  R((n+1):nCols,n)=fliplr(M(n,(n+1):nCols));
end
```